# Unable to add items to listview android eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, ftp

I want to add list of files and folders to a listview but unable to do so. I am very new to android programing. Any help please

```
public void ftpPrintFilesList(String dir_path)
{
    try {

        FTPFile[] ftpFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
        int length = ftpFiles.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String name = ftpFiles[i].getName();
            boolean isFile = ftpFiles[i].isFile();

            if (isFile) {
              //  Log.i(TAG, "File : " + name);
               arrayList.add("File : " + name);
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Directory : " + name);
                arrayList.add("Directory : " + name);

            }
        }
          ListView lv;
          lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your error message? What is not working? Is the list empty? Does the app crash`?

Comment: Listview remains empty.

Comment: could it be that your "int length" variable is 0?

Comment: I think no, I add lv.setAdapter code to a separate button then it works without any modification. I am not getting what is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your problem is the following:

> Your "dir_path" String contains an invalid directory

so that

```
mFTPClient.listFiles(dir_path);
```

returns an array with length 0. Therefore **your int length variable will be 0**, and therefore no items get added to the arrayList, and therefore your ListView is empty.

It could also be that you are getting a **NullPointer exception** inside your try - block because listview1 could not be found. This exception will not cause the app to crash since its in the try - block, however you should be able to see it in the log output.

Make sure you called setContentView(yourlayout) inside your Activity's onCreate() method.

**UPDATE:**

Since you are getting the **ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException** it means that you are executing your ftpPrintFilesList() method from another thread and not from the UI-Thread, where you called setContentView().
Move the call of ftpPrintFilesList() to the UI-thread to prevent this exception.

Comment: No the list is not empty. I checked it in logcat

Comment: Are you getting an exception (inside your try block) so that your code of initializing the Listview is not even executed?

Comment: yest there it is, "android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: If you got this `andro id.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`, that means you execute the job in another thread, try to move the block of code into `runOnUIThread` method. Hope this helps.